# How to make jAlert() like 'Please Wait' message.(without OK Button)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-blockui

How to make jAlert() Message Box without OK Button.

Basically what I want is to use jAlert() like Jquery Block UI

Comment: Maybe hiding the OK button with css?

Comment: Maybe [blockui](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bumts/2/.

There has been some modifications in the core jquery.alert.js, since there has been no overlay param. I made the changes to pass overlay (6th parameter) option to pass for it. You could replace the jquery.alert js code with my modified one.

```
$(function(){
$('#test').click(function(){$('#test3').jAlert('This is a jAlert Warning Box',"warning",'warningboxid', '', '', 1);});
});
```

Comment: Its ok, but it is not recommended to modify the core plugin, because it might create problem while upgrading. You could have used the better ones like blockui plugin. The plugin you choose does not seem to provide much options.

Comment: i already have blockui,i thought jAlert could done the thing...thats why... :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery events !!

Example ::
Case 1 : If you are trying to trigger your button after an interval
then use

```
setInterval( "clickRight()", 5000 );

function clickRight()
{
   $('.slide_right').trigger('click'); 
};
```

Case 2 : If you are waiting for user to type some thing on to an input field

```
$('#form').on('mousedown',function(e)
{
 if(e.which===1)
 {
   //call your function alerting message here//      
 }
}
```

Short Code ::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="whichkey" value="type something">
<div id="log"></div>
<script>
$('#whichkey').on('mousedown',function(e){
    alert("Error");
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```